# how to copy the QTableView header to the clipboard?

Tags: c++, qt

Is there a way to allow the header of a `QTableView` to be copied to the clipboard?

I have a table created with `QTableView` and `QAbstractTableModel`. To enable rowd and columns selection, I add this line to the constructor of my `QTableView`

```
setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection);
```

And to copy the data table to the clipboard I implemented the following function in a class that inherits from `QTableView`:

```
bool MyTableView::eventFilter(QObject * obj, QEvent * event) {
    if(event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress ) {
        auto* keyEvent = dynamic_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
        if (keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_C && (keyEvent->modifiers() == Qt::ControlModifier)) {
            QModelIndexList cells = selectedIndexes();
            std::sort(cells.begin(), cells.end()); // Necessary, otherwise they are in column order

            QString text;
            int currentRow = 0; // To determine when to insert newlines
            foreach (const QModelIndex& cell, cells) {
                if (text.length() == 0) {
                    // First item
                } else if (cell.row() != currentRow) {
                    // New row
                    text += '\n';
                } else {
                    // Next cell
                    text += '\t';
                }
                currentRow = cell.row();
                text += cell.data().toString();
            }
            QApplication::clipboard()->setText(text);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

The above function allows me to copy any cell/row and even column of a table. The only problem is that I can't copy a table header to the clipboard. Is there a way to make the header selectable and copyable?

In `MyTableModel` class I implement the `flags` function to select the table items.

```
Qt::ItemFlags MyTableModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const {
    return QAbstractTableModel::flags(index) | Qt::ItemIsSelectable;
}
```

Any suggestion or idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `model()->headerData(column, Qt::Horizontal).toString()` to get header data, just collect list of column indexes from `selectedIndexes` before itarating over data and call it for each item, appending result to `text`.

To make header selectable you need to override default `QHeaderView` behaviour, by default clicking on header section makes whole row or column selected.